# Watch subfolders and transform changed files

Tags: javascript, babeljs

i have the following folder structure:

```
|-- public
    |-- _category1
        |-- foo.js
        |-- bar.js
    |-- _category2
        |-- test.js
    |-- _...
|-- src
    |-- _category1
        |-- foo.js
        |-- bar.js
    |-- _category2
        |-- test.js
    |-- _...
```

The files in the src folder are ES6, the files in the public folder have to be ES5.

Is there a way to observe the src folder and it's subfolders for changes (i.e. file saved) and transform those files (not the whole directory) into the corresponding subfolder in the public folder?

My current solution is to manually use:

`npx babel sourcefile --out-file targetfile`

Thanks in advance

---

Thanks to MTCoster's answer i came up with the stupidly simple answer

```
npx babel src --out-dir public --watch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re looking for the `--watch` option:

> To compile a file **every time that you change it**, use the `--watch` or `-w` option:
>
> ```
> npx babel script.js --watch --out-file script-compiled.js
> ```

*From the [Babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli).*

Comment: thanks for the answer, but wouldn't that just watch 1 file instead of all files in the folder?

Comment: If that file imports other files in your project, babel should be smart enough to register watchers for those files too. As in 90% of cases, the solution here is just *try it and see what happens*.